# ComponentSerializationService not deserializing all properties

Tags: c#

I'm using the ComponentSerializationService as found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.componentserializationservice(v=vs.110).aspx):

When you cut a control from the design service the serialize method gets called, and when you paste deserialize.

In my example - I have a simple button and I've changed the background color.

Serialize looks like this :

```
public object Serialize(ICollection objects)
      {
         var serializationService = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ComponentSerializationService)) as ComponentSerializationService;

         if (serializationService == null)
         {
            throw new Exception("ComponentSerializationService not found");
         }

         SerializationStore returnObject;

         using (var serializationStore = serializationService.CreateStore())
         {
            foreach (object obj in objects)
            {
               if (obj is Control)
               {
                  serializationService.Serialize(serializationStore, obj);
               }                  
            }

            returnObject = serializationStore;
         }

         return returnObject;
      }
```

And Deserialize looks like this :

```
public ICollection Deserialize(object serializationData)
      {
         var serializationStore = serializationData as SerializationStore;

         if (serializationStore == null)
         {
            return new object[] {};
         }

         var componentSerializationService = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ComponentSerializationService)) as ComponentSerializationService;

         if (componentSerializationService == null)
         {
            throw new Exception("ComponentSerializationService not found");
         }

         var collection = componentSerializationService.Deserialize(serializationStore);

         return collection;
      }
```

I've set breakpoints in both methods and the incoming object contains the correct background property, but once deserialized the property is not persisted.

Any ideas welcome. This is a tricky class with very little in the line of code samples or documentation.

Comment: Have you tried using the overload method as documented in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyft4ewk(v=vs.110).aspx) Sounds like the reason why the background did not get persisted as there's no container?

Comment: Have you tried the Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert? This serializes/deserializes any complex type. I've used it before and it's great.

Comment: I'm am sure your problem is: once you cast your SerializationStore to object .... you no longer know what it is... so in your Deserialize you should not be able to cast it back to SerializationStore, you should set up a simple test to prove this. Also you are not showing what serializationService.Serialize(serializationStore, obj); does... personally i think your over complicating it. why not use normal serialize and deserialize.... type implementation.Why the need for the custom one? edit i see ComponentSerializationService is a provided ms class

Comment: Bounty or not, you'll get much better help if you provide a proper `mcve`. Without that, all you can get is a guesswork and the bounty is just waste of rep.

Comment: You are not showing enough code, we don't know how did you implement the ComponentSerializationService, then we can't say if there is something wrong in Serialize or Deserialize. Your problem is might not in what you are showing actually.

Comment: Needs the implementation of ComponentSerializationService. It seems your implementation is IDisposable. In the Serialize method your returnObject will be disposed. Returning a disposed object seems iffy to me.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this, and see if the SerializeAbsolute works for you :)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.componentserializationservice.serializeabsolute(v=vs.110).aspx

More specifically the Remark and I quote

> Standard serialization, as implemented through the Serialize method,
>   only serializes values that differ from the component's default state.
>   This provides the most compact serialization mechanism but assumes
>   that a newly created object will be used during deserialization. If an
>   existing object is used, the resulting deserialized object is not
>   guaranteed to duplicate the original state of the serialized object;
>   the properties that contained default values during serialization will
>   not be reset back to their defaults during deserialization. The
>   SerializeAbsolute method does not use this shortcut. It serializes all
>   properties of the source object so that deserialization can restore
>   all the object's properties, regardless of default state.